# Missing application-http-authentication in JBoss EAP 7.4 standalone.xml which uses ApplicationDomain

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

In the EAP 7.4 security architecture guide it says,

Chapter 4. Elytron Subsystem Example Scenarios
4.1.1. Security
For securing applications, JBoss EAP comes preconfigured with application-http-authentication for using HTTP and application-sasl-authentication for using SASL. The application-http-authentication http-authentication-factory uses ApplicationDomain which uses ApplicationRealm and groups-to-roles for authentication. ApplicationRealm is a properties-realm backed by application-users.properties and application-roles.properties for username, password, and role information.

But in my standalone.xml I do not see this. I only see one which uses ManagementDomain,

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:13.0" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
            ...
            <http-authentication-factory name="management-http-authentication" security-domain="ManagementDomain" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
                <mechanism-configuration>
                    <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST">
                        <mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                    </mechanism>
                </mechanism-configuration>
            </http-authentication-factory>
            <provider-http-server-mechanism-factory name="global"/>
        </http>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done in the undertow subsystem:

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
```

for example